# Generate HTML page using rails without a webserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webserver, html-generation

is possible to generate an HTML page using Ruby on Rails framework without using a webserver?
I want do something like this:

```
html = RailsHTMLGenerator.generate('path/to/rails/root', '/posts/540')
puts html
```

The first parameter is the `Rails.root`, the second is the HTTP path, and the function return the HTML of that page as string.

Someone can tell me how to do this? Ty.

Comment: Are you accessing this information from another app ? ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
require '/path/to/application.rb'
app = APPName::Application.initialize!
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(app)
session.get '/'
puts session.body
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do that from the Rails console

```
app.get '/foo'
```

This is how the console is initialized in case you want to try this approach:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb